# devise_token_auth: how to sign in a user after signup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-token-auth

I have successfully migrated to `devise_token_auth` (from `simple_token_authentication`), however for UX reasons I'd like to allow a user to sign up for their account, use their account immediately (previously done by returning a token in the signup response), and then confirm their email to unlock certain functionality. How can one achieve this flow via this gem?

Answer (score 1):

The user is by default signed in after registering.

You can grab the access-token and other information from the query string of the url that you set as the confirm_success_url i.e the url to which the user gets redirected to after signup. Use that authentication token to make a request to the server for protected resources.

Comment: Remove `confirmable` from the list of devise modules in your user model. Also, what does your devise_token_auth initializer look like?